# Java client fails to connect to local Flink cluster

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

I am trying out a small program with a local Flink cluster, setup according to the instructions [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html). The sample wordcount program runs fine, but when I attempt to run my own program, it stalls and fails while connecting to the job manager. This is Flink 1.5 with JDK 1.8

The relevant part of the code is

```
FlinkPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(FlinkPipelineOptions.class);
options.setStreaming(true);
options.setFlinkMaster("localhost:6123");
options.setRunner(FlinkRunner.class);
```

I start the cluster with start-cluster.sh, and I can see the two processes (job and task managers) are running. The logs on Flink don't have much. On the client side, after turning on debug, I can see the following

`18:43:20.507 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO akka.remote.Remoting - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink@talonx:38183]
18:43:20.511 [main] INFO org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient - Actor system started at akka.tcp://flink@talonx:38183
18:43:20.511 [main] INFO org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient - Submitting job with JobID: dbf63281771465550fd3598b2b67b91f. Waiting for job completion.
Submitting job with JobID: dbf63281771465550fd3598b2b67b91f. Waiting for job completion.
18:43:20.521 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor - Received SubmitJobAndWait(JobGraph(jobId: dbf63281771465550fd3598b2b67b91f)) but there is no connection to a JobManager yet.
18:43:20.522 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor - Received job test-talonx-0618131319-b721a69a (dbf63281771465550fd3598b2b67b91f).
18:43:20.523 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor - Disconnect from JobManager null.`

After a while, I get the following exception on the client

`19:03:19.396 [main] ERROR org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner - Pipeline execution failed
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:492)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:456)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:449)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.RemoteStreamEnvironment.executeRemotely(RemoteStreamEnvironment.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.RemoteStreamEnvironment.execute(RemoteStreamEnvironment.java:176)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.executePipeline(FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.java:126)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner.run(FlinkRunner.java:115)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:297)
    at Test.main(Test.java:106)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.awaitJobResult(JobClient.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.submitJobAndWait(JobClient.java:387)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:481)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActorConnectionTimeoutException: Lost connection to the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActor.handleMessage(JobClientActor.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.FlinkUntypedActor.handleLeaderSessionID(FlinkUntypedActor.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.FlinkUntypedActor.onReceive(FlinkUntypedActor.java:71)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:165)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:95)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)`

What might be missing here?

Comment: Are you using Flink `1.5` with legacy mode? Per default you should use the Flip-6 mode where you don't have a `StandaloneClusterClient` anymore. Please check that the client also uses Flink `1.5`.

Comment: I don't see any option to set/unset the legacy mode. The client is actually using 1.4, as that's the Maven dependency that came with Beam's Flink Runner. I'll try with 1.5

Comment: When running Flink `1.5` you can set `mode: legacy` in you `flink-conf.yaml` to activate the legacy mode. Per default it uses the new mode.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with both modes, it still fails with the same error. Using Flink 1.5 on the client now.

Comment: The cluster and client configuration should be the same. Could you please post the error you are seeing with `1.5` (default mode)? It would also be helpful to see the logs of the client and the cluster entrypoint.

Comment: I turned on debug in the log4j.properties on the Flink cluster, and narrowed it down to an incompatible class error. Looks like the latest (2.4.0) Beam's jars have  Flink 1.4 dependencies other than just the flink-core jar, so I need to either run 1.4 on the cluster or recompile Beam with Flink 1.5. I had replaced just flink-core to 1.5 in the client classpath. Also, it would be nice if such errors were output at the ERROR level and not debug on Flink.